# What is the alternative to "'llc -march=cpp" in LLVM 12

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

LLVM used to provide `llc -march=cpp test.ll -o test.cpp` instruction to learn C++ API, but this is not available in llvm 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no alternative. The reason why C++ backend was removed long time ago is quite simple: it did not serve its main intention to be a guide to LLVM C++ API well, it generated suboptimal code and was not updated to support the latest changes to C++ API.

You can use the code of existing transformation passes to learn LLVM C++ API

Comment: LLVM is really difficult to learn, and most of the information on the Internet is outdated